# QUdpSocket - datagram is being received twice, why?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qudpsocket

I am receiving a datagram twice on my QUdpSocket even though I am watching on wireshark and it is only received once.  I create the socket and listen on port 11112.  There is another device that emits data on this port which I am listening for. I consistently get two messages for each actual message sent. Im not sure what is causing this.  Any thoughts?

Stripped down code :

```
    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    m_socket = new QUdpSocket(this);
          connect (m_socket, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)), this, SLOT(onSocketStateChange(QAbstractSocket::SocketState)));
          m_socket->bind(11112, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    delete m_socket;
}

void MainWindow::readPendingDatagrams()
{
    QByteArray buffer;
    QHostAddress sender;
    quint16 port;

    while(m_socket->hasPendingDatagrams())
    {
        int s = m_socket->pendingDatagramSize();
        buffer.resize(s);
        //for some reason there are two datagrams on the line.
        // I have verified with wireshark that there is only one from the
        // sender so not sure what is happening under the hood...
        m_socket->readDatagram(buffer.data(),buffer.size(),&sender, &port);

        QString source = sender.toString().split(":")[3];
        if (source == "172.20.23.86")
        {
            qInfo() << buffer <<endl;
        }
    }


}

void MainWindow::onSocketStateChange(QAbstractSocket::SocketState state)
{
    if ( state == QAbstractSocket::BoundState ) {
           connect(m_socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readPendingDatagrams()));
       }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This may happen if the datagram is sent to a broadcast address, and you’re bound to all interfaces (0.0.0.0), and there are two interfaces the datagram is received on. To exclude this possibility, switch to the `receiveDatagram` API and dump the full details of the datagram you’ve received. My bet is that the interfaces you receive it on will be different each time.

You're also connecting the `readPendingDatagrams` slot potentially multiple times, and it may thus be fired multiple times, although `hasPendingDatagrams` should return `false` the second time round - so while this may be not be *the* problem, it is *a* problem that you must fix. It should only be connected once - when you construct the socket, i.e. in the constructor.

Comment: Can you clarify how I am connecting readPendingDatagrams multiple times?

Comment: I changed the code as suggested with no change to the behavior

Comment: @CarlBartlett You were connecting multiple times because you did connect each time the socket became bound. This may occur multiple times during the application lifetime, and is an unnecessary complication anyway: there's no point to connecting to the signal later.

Comment: I verified with break points, the socket is only bound once, although in principle I agree, it is not connecting multiple times.

Comment: The socket may be bound once, but it may bind to multiple interfaces...

Comment: Moved it to be certain.  Still the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Unslander Monica is correct, it binds to all interfaces default, you can fix it by m_socket->bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost,11112);